# Link the page number in a table

Tags: tables, numbering, citing, links

I use this table to make a description of the Symbol and mention the page number in which it is located

```
\documentclass[14pt,twoside]{extreport}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.4} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{llc}
\textbf{Symbol} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{page}\\[5pt]
 \hline
$\mathbb{G}$ & text here & 2\\
$V$ & text here & 3\\
$\mathcal{E}$ & text here& 5 
\end{tabular}
\newpage
text text text text text text text 

$\mathbb{G}$
\newpage
text text text text text text text 

$V$
\newpage
text text text text text text text 
\newpage
text text text text text text text 

$\mathcal{E}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Above table is written manually when adding a page numbering will be different.

How do I work linked to the page where there is Symbol so that when you change the page changes the page number in the table?

> magula's answer is good for above example, but when you use the master thesis
>   template does not work

Comment: If it doesn't work with some other template, please specify which exact template that is and how it doesn't work (throws errors/gives wrong result/...).

Comment: @magula   
Do not work in thesis template ... appear on the form ??

Comment: Did you compile it twice?

Comment: @magula yes I do, Note The thesis template is composed of several chapters separated ... This may populate the question mark

Comment: As I said: "please specify which exact template". If you would provide a minimal example (MWE), we'd have a chance to reproduce the problem and see what's going on. (Also, deleting the .aux files may be worth a try.)

Comment: @magula Thank you very much, I found the reason ... I am grateful to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the point where you use the symbol (say `\xi`) add a label, i.e. write `\xi\label{xi}`. Then, in the table, use `\pageref{xi}` to reference the page where the symbol was used.

You might have to compile the document twice for it to print the reference.

In your example, for the symbol \mathbb{G}, you would have to change

```
$\mathbb{G}$
```

to

```
$\mathbb{G}\label{G}$
```

and

```
$\mathbb{G}$ & text here & 2\\
```

to

```
$\mathbb{G}$ & text here & \pageref{G}\\
```

Comment: There are errors when executing

Comment: Can you solve the example above

Comment: You'll have to be more specific than that. What are the errors? What exactly did you change in your code?

Comment: Sorry, it should be `\pageref{xi}`, of course.

Comment: Thank you very much, I found the reason ... I am grateful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\label` and  `\pageref`:

```
\documentclass[14pt,twoside]{extreport}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{llc}
        \textbf{Symbol} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{page}\\[5pt]
        \hline
        $\mathbb{G}$ & text here & \pageref{sym-G}\\
        $V$ & text here & \pageref{sym-V}\\
        $\mathcal{E}$ & text here& \pageref{sym-E}
    \end{tabular}
    \newpage
    text text text text text text text 

    $\mathbb{G}$\label{sym-G}
    \newpage
    text text text text text text text 

    $V$\label{sym-V}
    \newpage
    text text text text text text text 
    \newpage
    text text text text text text text 

    $\mathcal{E}$\label{sym-E}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do not work in thesis template ... appear on the form ??

Comment: "Do not work" is not a useful description of the problem. It needs TWO latex runs!

Comment: I am sorry my English language is not good ... but I tried more than once and did not get a result except a question mark .... Note The thesis template is composed of several chapters separated ... This may populate the question mark

Comment: did my example work?

Comment: Thank you very much, I found the reason ... I am grateful to you.